# Enter password once in shell script of moving files linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am copying files to another server and I have this command:

```
scp -r "${inclr}" utzfin@utzfin1:"${backuppath}/${time_stamp}"
scp -r "${podout}" utzfin@utzfin1:"${backuppath}/${time_stamp}"
```

I keep getting a password prompt. is there a way of passing the password only once and the rest of the Commands executes without asking for password?

Comment: No, but `scp` supports copying multiple source files to a single destination. You could also use ssh keys instead of passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case sharing the ssh key of the target on source server or vice versa will do the needful and it will not ask for the password.

With below command you can generate the ssh key for the user and then share the id_rsa.pub key on another server.

ssh-keygen -t rsa

Command to share the key :-

ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@hostname